# XSLT function format-number not showing zeroes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml like this:

`<test>1.3122000000031211</test>`

With xslt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(test, '#.##########')" />
```

I'm getting result **1.3122**. Is it possible to get **1.3122000000**? When I have value like this **1.31225642115696** I'm getting **1.3122564211** which is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `0` instead of `#`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(test, '0.0000000000')" />
```

You can refer to the offical documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number

Answer (score 2):

If you use a zero `0` instead of `#` then even non significant zeroes will be output: `format-number(test, '0.00000000000')"`.